# How to handle assets (css, js, etc) with Django?

Tags: python, django, standards, twitter-bootstrap, conventions

I'm new to Django and to Python, and I've just completed Django's "build your first app" tutorial. I found it fantastic. However it never spoke about stylesheets, javascripts or anything of the like.

Where should they go? Currently my project directory looks like this:

```
myproject
  +app1
  +app2
  +myproject
  +public
    +css
    +img
    +js
  +templates
```

Am I doing it correctly? I would like to stick to Django/Python standards as much as possible. Also, if I would like to include certain styles and scripts in all of my templates, how can I do that? Let's say I'm using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably take a closer look at [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

Basically you can put a static folder in each of your apps (similar to your template folders) and the more general stuff (base.css, project-wide icons, jquery-plugins) in a static folder in your project root.

So the layout might look like this:

```
myproject
  +app1
    +static
      +app1
        +css
        +js
  +app2
  +static
    +css
    +img
```

Once you deploy your project you can use, the [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-the-app-and-your-static-files-from-the-same-server)-command from contrib.staticfiles to collect all your static files to a single directory (`STATIC_ROOT`) where you can serve it from.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to call the +public folder +static, and put the +template (app specific) folder inside the application that is using them (so to avoid confusion and to be able to use a template with a different name twice), also I don't understand why you put +myproject inside your root project.

Comment: That's how Django generated my directory structure when I used `django-admin.py startproject mysite`